# I was trying to connect my react frontend with java backend using axios. But I got stuck as "'then' is undefined" runtime error occurs

Tags: reactjs, http, axios

```
function HelloWorldRestApiCall() {
    axios.get('http://localhost:8080/hello-world')
         .then((response) => successfulResponse(response))
         .catch((error) => errorResponse(error))
         .finally(() => console.log("clean-up"))
}

function successfulResponse(response) {
    console.log(response)
    // setMessage(response.data)
    setMessage(response.data)
}
```

I tried with different URLs but it's not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not clear what is axios in your case but I suggest trying following:

- Somewhere at the boot:

```
    import axios from 'axios';

    const api = axios.create();
```

- In your component:

```
    import { api } from 'src/boot/axios';

    function HelloWorldRestApiCall() {
        api.get('http://localhost:8080/hello-world')
             .then((response) => successfulResponse(response))
             .catch((error) => errorResponse(error))
             .finally(() => console.log("clean-up"))
    }
```

Also, try using routing so your request from `/` is rerouted to `http://localhost:8080` for dev server, then you can just call `api.get('/hello-world')`.